# Fire SelectedIndexChanged event programmatically

Tags: asp.net, events

I have a project in asp.net wherein I use UserControl's and desire the following:

1. UserControl has the datagrid dg and this UserControl has the SelectedIndexChanged event for the datagrid: `dg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`
2. I want to fire the `dg_SelectedIndexChanged` for the datagrid from another class file clas1.cs when I set the selected index of the datagrid with the function `SetDataGridSelectIndex(DataGrid dg, int CellIndex`) in the class1.cs

this function in the usercontrol file:

```
void dg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // ...
}
```

this function in the class1.cs class:

```
private static void SetDataGridSelectIndex(DataGrid dg, int CellIndex)
{
    try
    {
        dg.SelectedIndex = -1; // this line set sleceted index to -1
        dg.SelectedIndex = dg.Items.Count - 1; // this line change the selected index,
// I WANT HERE TO FIRE THE dg_SelectedIndexChanged AUTOMATICALLY. BECAUSE OF THE INDEX CHANGE 

    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { }
}
```

I want when i call the SetDataGridSelectIndex(dg, 3) with passing to it the datagrid dg, it automatically fire the selectedindexchanged of the dg

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

1. Expose a public property in your UserControl that calls the SelectedIndexChanged event for the datagrid.
2. Pass the UserControl into the Class1 instance and call the public property from there.

Comment: thank you sir; but i want to fire the selectedindexchanged of the datagrid within the function: private static void SetDataGridSelectIndex(DataGrid dg, int CellIndex) { try { dg.SelectedIndex = -1; dg.SelectedIndex = dg.Items.Count - 1; } catch (Exception ex) { } } ...  the two lines dg.SelectedIndex = -1; dg.SelectedIndex = dg.Items.Count - 1; make change in the datagrid but this don't fire selectedindexchanged  event.